# Proof for $HK = \operatorname{grp}\{H \cup K\} \iff HK \text{ is a subgroup of } G$

Tags: group-theory

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G,*$, how can one proof that:
$$HK = \operatorname{grp}\{H \cup K\} \iff HK \text{ is a subgroup of } G$$

I've seen similar proofs on the internet, but there the subgroups $H$ and $K$ were normal subgroups. I think it is also possible to prove with subgroups, but can't figure out how to prove it without the condition of normal subgroups.

Comment: I assume $grp\{X\}$ denotes the subgroup of $G$ generated by the set $X$?

Comment: @Belgium_Physics And in Group Theory one denotes this as $\langle X \rangle$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $HK$ is the subgroup generated by $H\cup K$, then it is of course a subgroup.

On the other hand, if $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$, then it is clearly the smallest subgroup containing both $H$ and $K$ (as any such subgroup must contain all $hk$ with $h\in H$, $k\in K$).